# android: Is it possible to sell add-ons for apps in the Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to distribute my app for free, and then sell extra features that can be added-on later. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: btw: similar question is also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042603/is-paypal-in-app-model-for-android-legal-on-android-market and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787738/paypal-as-in-app-payment-model-in-android .... but as you can see from the replies, nobody really knows for sure... just need to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about in-app payment, you should take a look at PayPal, which offers In-App-Payment for Android:

http://www.x.com

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks

If you want to distribute your app via Android Market, you would need to offer each add-on as an invididual app. Probably not a convenient way.

Comment: isn't it against the TOS to take payments through something like the PayPal model? So, let's say I make a game, and I want to sell additional levels each level I sell would have to be it's own app? Or is there a way to tell the system to install the new "app" into the structure of the old one?

Comment: well, nobody from Google ever replies to these kind of questions on the dev group or elsewhere, so I'd say just do it and see if it works or not; worst that can happen is your app gets kicked off. But I haven't heard of any so far. This question is frequently asked on LinkedIn, Dev group, etc. I'd say just give it a try... On LinkedIn see: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6c4a20fdb501409b/ebdd26300c680c12?lnk=gst&q=paypal#

Comment: btw: it's not a new app, you add additional features into the app and need to handle the logic within your one app.

Comment: so, is there a way to write an additional feature that can be sold in the android market that gets installed to the original app?

Comment: or do i have to always just write one version that is free without the feature and one version that is paid with the feature, both being fully buit apps.

Comment: both ways work in general but it depends on the nature of your app. If you just want to offer one 'pro' version with one additional feature set (which the user pays once), it's ok; if you want to offer a 100 optional features, adding 100 apps to the market is not a good approach. If you want to offer lots of features, you should use in-app payment. Need to know the nature of your app to know which approach would work best.

Comment: Ok. So if, in my app, I want to be able to add lets say 10 optional features be it additional content, extra levels, whatever. In order to make it so that this content gets installed to the original app as opposed to each version being a seperate app does it need to be an in-app purchase using something like the paypal model, or could I sell the features in some type of package on the android market. Then when said feature is purchased through the market it should be installed to the original app.

Comment: You can look at the app "Steamy Pro" which is 0.99 in the market, which then offers an add-on package called "Steamy Pro Addon" for free. Ok, this is the other way around, but the concept is the same. You can do it this way via the Android market. But it requires that the user has to leave your app in order to purchase additional features. With InApp-Payment you keep the user inside your app. If you're developing a game where the user can buy extra items, weapons, etc. - sending him to the Android market to buy an item... is not very convenient and common from a user experience perspective.

Comment: On the Android market there is no such thing as 'additional package' added to an existing app, all apps are separate, but you need to develop them in a way that they can communicate with each other, share data, etc.

Comment: Ok, I see now. So doing it through the Android Market requires a complete app to be uploaded. So if I create an additional feature I want unlocked it would be a new app of some sort entirely. I would then build the 2 so they could talk to each other, but the user will see 2 apps on his handset. The only way around this, for now, is through something like the paypal in-app method which, unfortunately, runs the risk of having your app removed from the store. I think I get it now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes that's correct. But as said, I've not heard of any cases where an app uses PayPal has been removed from the market. Usually developers who follow the Android dev list would then already know of. Really, I suggest to just give it a try. But if the app gets rejected, you just change the app name and publish it again; with a changed payment concept then. Afaik Google Checkout doesn't offer in-app payment, but I haven't updated myself on that topic recently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.  There are addons all over the market for the better keyboard app.

Comment: Ok. I've been looking for tutorials on how to create an add-on package for an app. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not too sure, maybe someone else can chime in on this.  Take a look at these here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)#Java

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways you can do this, here are two ways I already tried.

1) You could implement all the features in the app and a key app that unlocks this features.
Here is a simple and insecure implementation, the key app and the main app need to be signed with the same key:

```
 public boolean isPackageAvailable(String packageName) {
                int sigMatch = getPackageManager().checkSignatures(getPackageName(), packageName);
                return sigMatch == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH;
        }
```

Check MarketEnabler on market-enabler.googlecode.com to see how I used it (not not a secure way but a starting point).

2) You include the plugin app as intent into a subview so it looks like just one app splitted to multiple apk's.

Check http://speakerproximity.googlecode.com where I used it to include the settings view inside the mainview:

```
....
public class SpeakerProximity extends ActivityGroup {
....
mainLayout.addView(getViewFromIntent("preferences", new Intent(
                                        this, PreferenceScreen.class)));
....
public View getViewFromIntent(String tag, Intent intent) {

                /** start an activity inside an ActivityGroup and get the window handler **/
                final Window w = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(tag, intent);

                /** extract the view out of the window handler **/
                final View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;

                return wd;
        }
...
```

Note that I extend ActivityGroup and not Activity ;-)